# SAS arrays to set a value if it maches a specific value in any of the column

Tags: sas

Im trying to set `any5 = 'Yes'` if there is a number 5 in any of the columns Q1 to Q5. However my code below only shows for the last column.

```
data survey; 
infile datalines firstobs=2; 
input ID 3. Q1-Q5; 
array score{5} _temporary_ (5,5,5,5,5); 
array Ques{5} Q1-Q5; 
do i =1 to 5; 
   if Ques{i} = score{i} then any5='Yes'; 
   else any5='No'; 
end; 
drop i; 
datalines;
ID  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 
535 1  3  5  4  2
12  5  5  4  4  3
723 2  1  2  1  1
7   3  5  1  4  2
; 
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple :-)

```
data survey;
infile datalines;
input ID 3. Q1-Q5;
array Ques{*} Q1 - Q5; 

any5 = ifc(5 in Ques, 'Yes', 'No');

datalines;
535 1  3  5  4  2
12  5  5  4  4  3
723 2  1  2  1  1
7   3  5  1  4  2
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [COUNTC](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.3/lefunctionsref/n1qcntq4r6p3w3n1mtsnm58tbomc.htm) function to compute the number of times 5 is repeated in your Q 1-Q5 columns then use the [IFC](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/1.0/lefunctionsref/p07za51a2k0sxkn1m0tulx2cy464.htm) function to return a character value based on whether the expression is true, false, or missing.

```
data survey; 
infile datalines firstobs=2; 
input ID 3. Q1-Q5; 
any5 = ifc(countc(cats(of Q:),'5')>0,'Yes','No');
datalines;
ID  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 
535 1  3  5  4  2
12  5  5  4  4  3
723 2  1  2  1  1
7   3  5  1  4  2
; 
run; 

Result:
   535 1 3 5 4 2 Yes
   12  5 5 4 4 3 Yes
   723 2 1 2 1 1 No
   7   3 5 1 4 2 Yes
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `WHICHN` function to determine the index of the target value in a list of values.

In your case assign the test for any index matching

```
any5 = whichn (5, of ques(*)) > 0;
```

From the documentation:

> #### WHICHN Function
>
> Searches for a numeric value that is equal to the first argument, and
> returns the index of the first matching value.
>
> Syntax
>
> `WHICHN(argument, value-1 <, value-2, ...>)`

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple mistake in your logic.  You are setting ANY5 to YES or NO on every time through the loop.  Since you continue going through the loop even after the match is found you overwrite the results from the previous times through the loop, so only the results of the last test survive.

Here is one way.  Set the answer to NO before the loop and remove the ELSE clause.

```
any5='No ';
do i =1 to 5; 
   if Ques{i} = 5 then any5='Yes'; 
end;
```

Or stop when you have your answer.

```
do i =1 to 5 until(any5='Yes'); 
   if Ques{i} = score{i} then any5='Yes'; 
   else any5='No';
end;
```

Or skip the looping altogether.

```
if whichn(5, of Q1-Q5) then any5='Yes'; 
else any5='No';
```

Or even easier create any5 as numeric instead of character.  SAS will return 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE as the result of a boolean expression.

```
any5 = ( 0 < whichn(5, of Q1-Q5) );
```